# Guidance on achieving this Guitar tone (Axe-fx Ultra)

Tags: electric-guitar, tone

Today I received my Fractal Axe-fx Ultra and would like to achieve the guitar tone in the below video. I'm crazy about this song.

I'm using the Axe-fx with a head (Peavy 6505 MH) and 1x12 Orange cabinet. The Axe is in the effects loop.

I have no experience with processors/ modellers and I'd like pointers in terms of cabs, amps, effects etc. I have no real idea of where to start (maybe find closest matching preset and go from there?).

Comment: You know that's not a guitar at all, right? Until I looked it up I honestly thought that was right out of 1987, actually laughed out loud when I found it is was meant to be a "new sound".

Comment: What on earth is it then? Sax? lol. I mean, I've already transcribed the whole thing and learned how to play it on guitar. If I could get as close as possible...

Comment: It's a synth, probably set to mono, judging by some of the note chokes. If it had actually been recorded mid 80s I'd have said it would definitely have been played through a Tom Scholtz Rockman to get the final sound. ***Everything*** in the 80s went through a Rockman - wish I still had mine, probably be worth something by now.

Comment: Fractal [Axe Change](https://axechange.fractalaudio.com/search-results.php?search=&fields=all&products=1&setups=1) search 'rockm' [not rockman, there are 2 others called rockmeon]  BTW, I've never heard either the Axe-FX or these presets so no guarantees

Comment: Cheers. I've just looked to their live videos. Everyone has had Sax playing, apart from one, the girl's tone was nothing like the one above. If I could get close, it'll be worth the cost of the Axe alone. But, yeah, I did have my suspicions as to whether it was guitar :)

Comment: There's a very lot of mid to late 80's American music that sounds like that. Have a look for some. This band *are* copying what was also a guitar style, lots of whammy bar, lots of very smooth distortion, heavy compression, usually with a chorus on it too [Either the Roland Dimension D or the one straight from the Rockman itself].

Comment: For a *very* quick history lesson, this is where is all started. This is Tom Scholz on guitar, [Boston: More than a feeling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oR4uKcvQbGQ) which was a direct response to Brian May's sound with Queen. By the mid 80's the Brits were doing this [Cutting Crew: Dies in Your Arms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6dOwHzCHfgA) which is slightly edgier than the US were doing at the time. contd...

Comment: …contd: & rather than try to find examples of all the US stuff, I found this guy who makes a decent job of a lot of it … & without a whammy. [Andrea Boma Boccarusso : 10 guitar solos from 80s pop music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nbkGUFxC78)

Comment: What guitar sound..?